# brick breaker game in android - detect hit(ball with break)

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, collision

My code now is

```java
private boolean checkHit2(int row, int col, Ball ball) {
    // Check for a hit from below
    if (ball.getTop()   <= this.getBrickBottom( row) &&
            ball.getTop()  >= this.getBrickTop(row) &&
            ball.getRight() >= this.getBrickLeft(col) &&
            ball.getLeft()  <= this.getBrickRight(col))
        return true;

    // Check for a hit from up
    if(ball.getBottom()  >= this.getBrickTop(row) &&
            ball.getBottom()  <= this.getBrickBottom(row) &&
            ball.getRight() >= this.getBrickLeft(col) &&
            ball.getLeft()  <= this.getBrickRight(col))
        return true;


    // No hit
    return false;
}

if(gameLevel.updateIfHit2(ballArr[i])){
                        if(ballArr[i].isBounceUp())
                            ballArr[i].down();
                        else
                            ballArr[i].bounceUp();
}
```

Which work good most of the time. The problem is that sometimes it detect more than one hit on the same brick because the condition in the code "checkHit2" still hold(true). (Each brick need more than 1 hit in order to disapper and sometimes after hit the brick it continue hit it instead of change direction (bouchup instead of down for example).

I also tried this code:

```java
private boolean checkHit(int row, int col, Ball ball) {
        // Check for a hit from below
        if (ball.getTop()   == this.getBrickBottom( row) &&
        //      ball.getTop()  >= this.getBrickTop(row) &&
                ball.getRight() >= this.getBrickLeft(col) &&
                ball.getLeft()  <= this.getBrickRight(col))
            return true;

        // Check for a hit from up
        if(ball.getBottom()  == this.getBrickTop(row) &&
            //  ball.getBottom()  <= this.getBrickBottom(row) &&
                ball.getRight() >= this.getBrickLeft(col) &&
                ball.getLeft()  <= this.getBrickRight(col))
            return true;


        // No hit
        return false;
    }
```

But it's problematic too

Answer (score 0):

You should use synchronized in your checkhit2 method so that it will finish each processing before being interleaved with other processing.

Comment: this is not theproblem -I only have one thread which call this method.The problem is that the in the thread's loop it call the methos maybe to frequent..

Answer (score 0):

If your ball is smaller than your brick and your update rate is not fine enough, then it's possible for the ball to travel right inside your brick which would give the results you describe. If this is the case, you can either:

- Increase your update rate (make the distance the ball travels before
  hit test smaller) which  will still be an issue for phones that have
  low performance.
- Make a third test for which, if the ball is entirely inside a brick
  (both cases are true) then you need to make a bounce decision based
  off a previous state of the ball.

All the best with your game!

Comment: thanks. the first suggestion is not good enuofh for me. about the second - yow wrote "if the ball is entirely inside a brick" - the problem I described can also be if just one of the condition hold

Comment: I can't provide you with much for assistance without knowing more about when/how the checkHit methods are called. Although given your comment, perhaps an easy solution would be to move the ball immediately once you've detected a hit? Or alternatively, store a list of row/column IDs which the ball has hit during this frame and check that the current row/column hasn't been tested against? (I don't recommend this method). As I said, I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code, so perhaps your problem is elsewhere. Good luck! :)